# Roblox Word Guessing Game

Tags: roblox

I am trying to make a word guessing game on roblox. Basically, there is a main lobby where the players wait during intermission. once the intermission is over, all of the players are teleported to a platform. This is where the game actually happens. At the top of the screen there is a label showing them the timer and the phrase. Each phrase has a 12 second time limit for the players to guess the word. Once the 12 seconds is up, the game checks to see who got it right. If a player got it wrong, they are teleported to the lobby. If they got it right, then they stay in the game and move on to the next phrase. This continues until there is one player left. who is then deemed the winner.

Below is the what I have so far in serverscriptservice. I am having trouble figuring out how I can recieve each players input and determine if they got it right or not. Any advice?

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local StarterGui = game:GetService("StarterGui")
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")

local Status = game.ReplicatedStorage.Status
local PhraseVar = game.ReplicatedStorage.PhraseVar





local NormalWords = {
    "american idol",
    "austin powers",
    "i smell a skunk",
    "its a small world",
    "julius caesar",
    "long overdue"
}

local WeirdWords = {
    "Huh Mere Eye Can Eye Dull",
    "Oz Temp Hours",
    "Ice Mail Ask Hunk",
    "Hit Says Mall Whirled",
    "Jewel Us Seize Her",
    "Lawn Gopher Do",

}



local Platforms = {
    game.Workspace.Platform1,
    game.Workspace.Platform2,
    game.Workspace.Platform3,
    game.Workspace.Platform4,
    game.Workspace.Platform5,
    game.Workspace.Platform6
}


-- Main Game While Loop
while true do

    PhraseVar.Value = "Preparing for round..."
    for i = 80, 1, -1 do
        Status.Value = i
        wait(1)
    end

    local allPlayers = Players:GetPlayers()
    for index, player in ipairs(allPlayers) do
        local platform = Platforms[index]
        if platform then
            local humanoidRootPart = player.Character:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
            if humanoidRootPart then
                humanoidRootPart.CFrame = platform.CFrame * CFrame.new(0, humanoidRootPart.Size.Y / 2 + 2, 0)
            end
        end
    end

    Status.Value = ""
    PhraseVar.Value = "Preparing Question..."
    wait(3)



    while true do
        local index = math.random(1, #WeirdWords)


        local correctAnswer = NormalWords[index]


        PhraseVar.Value = WeirdWords[index]
        
        local gotItRight = {}
        
        --For Loop that shows the textbox frame
        for _, player in pairs(allPlayers) do
            -- Check if the player has a PlayerGui
            if player:FindFirstChildOfClass("PlayerGui") then
                -- Find or create the UserInput screen GUI
                local userInputGui = player.PlayerGui:FindFirstChild("UserInput") or Instance.new("ScreenGui")
                userInputGui.Name = "UserInput"

                -- Find or create the UserInputFrame inside the screen GUI
                local userInputFrame = userInputGui:FindFirstChild("UserInputFrame") or Instance.new("Frame")
                userInputFrame.Name = "UserInputFrame"

                -- Set the visibility of the frame to true
                userInputFrame.Visible = true

                
                -- Make sure the UserInputFrame is a child of the PlayerGui
                userInputFrame.Parent = userInputGui
                userInputGui.Parent = player.PlayerGui
                

                
                
            end
        end
        
        -- Use the loop as the timer
        for i = 12, 1, -1 do
            Status.Value = i
            wait(1)
        end
        
        
        --Hides the texbox
        for _, player in pairs(allPlayers) do
            -- Check if the player has a PlayerGui
            if player:FindFirstChildOfClass("PlayerGui") then
                -- Find or create the UserInput screen GUI
                local userInputGui = player.PlayerGui:FindFirstChild("UserInput") or Instance.new("ScreenGui")
                userInputGui.Name = "UserInput"

                -- Find or create the UserInputFrame inside the screen GUI
                local userInputFrame = userInputGui:FindFirstChild("UserInputFrame") or Instance.new("Frame")
                userInputFrame.Name = "UserInputFrame"

                -- Set the visibility of the frame to true
                userInputFrame.Visible = false


                -- Make sure the UserInputFrame is a child of the PlayerGui
                userInputFrame.Parent = userInputGui
                userInputGui.Parent = player.PlayerGui




            end
        end
        
        PhraseVar.Value = NormalWords[index] 
        Status.Value = ""
        wait(3)
        PhraseVar.Value = "Preparing Next Question..." 
        wait(3)

    end

end
```